# What are these characters in mimetype octet-stream?

Tags: http, http-headers

following is my response data I cannot understand what kind of characters are these?

```
b'l\x00\x00\x00{"fk_bin_data_lib":"FKDATAHS101","user_id":"18","verify_mode":"1","io_mode":"0","io_time":"20190311120940"}\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I same problem with a attendance record. The communication manual is very complicated and it have examples very old or bads.

Finally I apply many test over device and can know that it make a request to server with a binary file and it shold be processed as binary and converted to String UTF-8.

After convert to UTF-8 you can parse it to JSON and process it.

I have a example reading it here https://github.com/erpcya/Attendance-Node-Example

With regex you can reeplace characters or cut for get your JSON pure.

Best regards